# Strange Height Size top menu

Tags: css

in my top menu for some reason appeared a height size that shouldn´t appear, the size of my top menu is the same of the hoover link menu (hoover) and it appears some height that i cant find from where it came. Here is the link:

```
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JsCGE/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the margin on the left and right classes.

```
#menu ul.right{
    float: right;
    margin: 0; /* Add this */
    }
    #menu ul.left{
    float: left;
    margin: 0; /* Add this */
    }
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes thanks, thats right, why that this height appeared?

Comment: There are some default vales that are automatically added in all browsers.  In the future, I would recommend using a css reset. I like to use this one here, from Eric Meyer: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/